# Overloading Operators Twice With Different Arguments

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to overload the `*` operator for a class, one which is in case it is multiplied by a real number `double` and the other is when multiplied by the same class type.

Below is my code:

```
class Vector2D {
    ...
    friend Vector2D operator* (const Vector2D&);
    friend Vector2D operator* (const double); // getting error here
};
```

The error I'm getting is: `'Vector2D operator*(double)' must have an argument of class or enumerated type`

Is it possible to overload operators more than once, and if so, why am I getting an error?

Comment: Why do you have to declare them as `friend` methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class Vector2D {
    ...
    friend Vector2D operator* (const Vector2D&);
```

That is overloading unary `operator*` (i.e. dereference operator) as a free function, not overloading the multiplication of two vectors. You cannot overload operators that apply only to non-class types, and that is the error for:

```
friend Vector2D operator* (const double);
```

You probably meant to write:

```
friend Vector2D operator*(const Vector2D&,const Vector2D&);
friend Vector2D operator*(const Vector2D&,double);
```

Comment: Ohh, so I was missing an argument in the overloading operators

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're overloading unary `operator*`, not binary. Your `friend` declarations are not member functions.

Either remove the `friend` (if you want to overload the operators as member functions), or else add a first parameter of type `const Vector2D&` or `Vector2D&` (if you want to overload as free functions). The latter is usually preferable, since then you get implicit conversion on both arguments -- member operator overloads will implicitly convert the right hand side but not the left.

The reason you might not want a reference as the first argument to binary `operator*`, is so that you can implement it like this:

```
Vector2D operator*(Vector2D lhs, const Vector2D &rhs) {
    lhs *= rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

The same would apply to addition (and addition of two vectors makes sense to me in a way that multiplication of two vectors does not).

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to override the operators for built-in types. In this case you're providing a declaration for a unary `*` operator for type `double` which isn't allowed.

I think you want to remove the `friend` declaration and make these member functions instead.